# How to get the text which has footnote in Word by C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a Word document. In this document, I have the words: "Microsoft SQL server 2008". I create footnote for this words. The content footnote is "Express Edition". Now I want to get the text "Microsoft SQL server 2008".

I have tried to search on the internet, but I can only find the way to get the content "Express Edition". I don't know how to get the text "Microsoft SQL server 2008". Thank you for your reading.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Footnote x in _activeDoc.Footnotes)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(x.Range.Text);
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the Footnotes object the footnote does not appear to be attached to any text (unlike a Comment) - it is inserted at a particular position in the file. You can use the Start & End properties of the Footnote's Reference object _(x.Reference)_ to find the location in the file & search back from there to find the preceding word.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just fixed it according to your idea.